# Setx Called From Java Not Working Correctly

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm using the [`setx`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc755104.aspx) command to modify the [`PATH`](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) system environment variable. Here is the command I'm using:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34" /M
```

When this is ran as [`batch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) file and as [administrator](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token), it works properly and adds the new entry to the `PATH`.

However if I'm trying to run this from within my `Java` application it starts to behave weirdly.

First of all, the Java code used to execute the batch file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class BatchFile
{
    public static void execute(String batchFilePath) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException
    {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + batchFilePath);
        process.waitFor();

        printResults(process);
    }

    private static void printResults(Process process) throws IOException
    {
        String standardOutput = getString(process.getInputStream());
        String standardError = getString(process.getErrorStream());

        if (!standardOutput.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println(standardOutput);
        }

        if (!standardError.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println(standardError);
        }
    }

    private static String getString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        return IOUtils.toString(inputStream).trim();
    }
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
BatchFile.execute("MyBat.bat");
```

Before running, my `PATH` looks like this:

```
c:\devkitPro\msys\bin;C:\devkitPro\devkitPPC\bin;C:\devkitPro\devkitPPC\powerpc-eabi\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\devkitPro\devkitARM\bin;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wiimm\WIT;C:\Windows\System32;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1;C:\Python34;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\SysWOW64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
```

After running the Java code however, it turns into this:

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;c:\devkitPro\msys\bin;C:\devkitPro\devkitPPC\bin;C:\devkitPro\devkitPPC\powerpc-eabi\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\devkitPro\devkitARM\bin;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wiimm\WIT;C:\Windows\System32;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1;C:\Python34;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\SysWOW64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files
```

The message being printed out on the console is as follows:

```
D:\Programs\Portable\Eclipse\workspace\My Application>setx PATH "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;c:\devkitPro\msys\bin;C:\devkitPro\devkitPPC\bin;C:\devkitPro\devkitPPC\powerpc-eabi\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\devkitPro\devkitARM\bin;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wiimm\WIT;C:\Windows\System32;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1;C:\Python34;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\SysWOW64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\Programs\Portable\Eclipse;;C:\Python34" /M 

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
```

As you can see, a lot of rubbish Java directories have been added to the `PATH` contents at the beginning and it exceed the maximum limit of 1024 characters so it cuts off at the end. At the end there is an unwanted Eclipse directory added and there also are two semicolons before the actual [`Python`](https://www.python.org/downloads/) path.

**How do I get rid of the unwanted behavior when invoking the batch file using Java?** I want the correct default behavior like when the `setx` command is invoked normally on [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe).

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I was stuck at the same problem.

The simple answer is: 
Do not use eclipse to start your program.

Eclipse will change your environment variables quite a lot for the execution. (including PATH)
You might have guessed it now but eclipse closes the PATH with a ; so when you call

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34" /M
```

you add another ; in front of the python path.

Just check by changing your batch to

```
echo %PATH%
```

Then run from eclipse and make another testrun from the command line (java -cp . MyMainClass) to see the difference.

Regarding the "WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters." limitation of setx you might want to have a look there: https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx